# Can you cancel an automatic landing triggered by a low battery on the Dji Mavic 2 Pro?

Tags: batteries, dji-mavic-2

Whenever the DJI Mavic 2 Pro has a low battery it initiates a function that lands it. Sometimes this can happen when the drone still has a lot of battery capacity e.g. 45%.

Is there a way to cancel this return to home function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have more then enough battery, you can disable it as stated [in the manual](https://forum.dji.com/thread-173775-1-1.html):

> ## Low Battery RTH
>
> Low Battery RTH is triggered when the Intelligent Flight Battery is depleted to the point that the safe return of the aircraft may be affected. Return home or land the aircraft immediately when prompted. DJI GO 4 displays a warning when the battery level is low. The aircraft will automatically return to the Home Point if no action is taken after a ten-second countdown. **The user can cancel RTH by pressing the RTH button or Flight Pause button on the remote controller.**

Note: this function is intimated specifically so the drone has enough battery to come back to you, so if you cancel it, make sure you know what you’re doing.

The function can not be overridden if the drone only has enough battery to descend from its current altitude:

> **The aircraft will land automatically if the current battery level can only support the aircraft long enough to descend from its current altitude. The user cannot cancel the auto-landing but can use the remote controller to alter the aircraft’s orientation during the landing process.**